# Angular 2 localization with Gettext ( .po files)

Tags: angular, gettext

I have old legacy site translated of 4 different languages with Gettext and .po files.

Now I am starting rebuilding of the site, and trying to use those files in new Angular2 site.

Is there any way I could directly use .po files?

I have tried `https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate` with `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@biesbjerg/ng2-translate-po-loader`
but It's not working properly when passing params to string.

Then I tried some converters, to convert .po to JSON, but they are adding some nulls and arrays...

For example converting:

```
msgid "meta:Reporting"
msgstr "Reporting"
```

I get:

```
"meta:Reporting": [
    null,
    "Reporting"
]
```

Instead of

```
"meta:Reporting" : "Reporting"
```

Is there way to use directly .po files in Angular2?

Answer (score 10):

I use [`ngx-translate`](http://www.ngx-translate.com/) together with [`ngx-translate-po-http-loader`](https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-po-http-loader). I use them together with [`ngx-translate-extract`](https://github.com/biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract) to extract text from my `.ts`-fies to one or more `.pot`-files